# interp2(V,k) from Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to convert this version of interp2 from Matlab to Python.
In Matlab is used as

```
Vq = interp2(V,k)
```

Which perform interpolation over a matrix `V` where each original interval has been recursively subdivided `k` times. Adding a total of `2^k-1` elements to each division. 
However I haven't found a Python alternative to this function. I tried with `scipy.interpolation.interp2` but only works with three matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this alternative in a [Forum](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2009-February/019996.html), looks like an email transcription, but I´ll paste the answer here anyways.

```
import numpy as np


def interp2d_interleave(z,n):
    '''performs linear interpolation on a grid

    all points are interpolated in one step not recursively

    Parameters
    ----------
    z : 2d array (M,N)
    n : int
    number of points interpolated

    Returns
    -------
    zi : 2d array ((M-1)*n+M, (N-1)*n+N)
        original and linear interpolated values

    '''
    frac = np.atleast_2d(np.arange(0,n+1)/(1.0+n)).T
    zi1 = np.kron(z[:,:-1],np.ones(len(frac))) + np.kron(np.diff(z),frac.T)
    zi1 = np.hstack((zi1,z[:,-1:]))
    zi2 = np.kron(zi1.T[:,:-1],np.ones(len(frac))) + np.kron(np.diff(zi1.T),frac.T)
    zi2 = np.hstack((zi2,zi1.T[:,-1:]))
    return zi2.T

def interp2d_interleave_recursive(z,n):
    '''interpolates by recursively interleaving n times
    '''
    zi = z.copy()
    for ii in range(1,n+1):
        zi = interp2d_interleave(zi,1)
    return zi
```

This should be used as follows

```
xyz = np.zeros((2, 2))
xyz = interp2d_interleave_recursive(xyz, 1)
```

And the result would be:
[image]